# Can I get into Python and code in my own brushes?

Tags: python, scripting, sculpting

Say I want some behavior like the brushes on zbrush or want to combine 2 brushes at the same time will I be able to do that?
--want to get a sculpt brush like the polish brush from zbrush and
--the one pinch/crease brush form zbrush t

Comment: Hello, please narrow down your actual usecase. A few screenshots or diagrams help, too :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, you might have better time to mix the alphas of those two brushes in a program like Krita or Photoshop.

Then make the resulting alpha as a brush in Blender. Here is a tutorial that talks about that: https://youtu.be/JJtNfDKHzmo